# How Can I Center Text Next To Font Awesome

Tags: html, css

Basically I want to center a Steam Logo with Font Awesome next to some text so I can increase the text size. The only problem is I can't center the steam logo vertically and I also can't get the text center next to it vertically. It decides to sit under the logo for some reason. Any help is appreciated!

```css
    /* Default Stuff */
    * {
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
     text-decoration:none;
     list-style:none;
     font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
    }

    /* Loading Animation */
    .loading-spinner {
     width:100px;
     height:100px;
     border:2px solid rgb(255,255,255);
     border-top:3px solid rgb(250,32,32);
     border-radius:100%;
     position:absolute;
     top:0px;
     bottom:0px;
     left:0px;
     right:0px;
     margin:auto;
     animation:loading-spin 1s infinite linear;
    }

    @keyframes loading-spin {
     from {
      transform:rotate(0deg);
     } to {
      transform:rotate(360deg);
     }
    }

    #loading-overlay {
     height:100%;
     width:100%;
     background:rgb(17,17,17);
     position:fixed;
     z-index:9999999999;
     left:0px;
     top:0px;
    }

    /* Website Header */
    #header {
     background:rgb(28,28,28);
     width:100%;
     height:60px;
     position:absolute;
     box-shadow:0px 0px 8px 2px black;
     border-top:3px solid rgb(235,50,50);
     z-index:99999999;
     left:0px;
     top:0px;
    }

    .steam-login {
     background:rgb(50,50,50);
     border-left:3px solid rgb(235,50,50);;
     width:160px;
     height:40px;
     position:absolute;
     z-index:999999999;
     top:13px;
     left:1160px;
    }

    .steam-login a {
     display:block;
     color:rgb(255,255,255);
     height:100%;
     width:100%;
     margin-left:5px;
     font-size:30px;
    }

    .sign-in-text {
     color:white;
     font-size:8px;
     position:absolute;
     margin-left:50px;
    }

    /* Sidebar Menu */
    #sidebar-menu {
     background:rgb(41,41,41);
     width:60px;
     height:100%;
     position:absolute;
     text-align:center;
     line-height:60px;
     box-shadow:4px 4px 8px black;
     left:0px;
     top:0px;
    }

    ul {
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
     margin-top:3px;
    }

    ul li {
     list-style:none;
     height:60px;
     border-bottom:2px solid rgb(17,17,17);
    }

    ul li a {
     color:rgb(255,255,255);
     font-size:30px;
     display:block;
     height:100%
     width:100%;
    }

    ul li a:hover {
     background:rgb(255,255,255);
     color:rgb(41,41,41);
    }

    ul li a:active {
     font-size:25px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Loading Animation-->
  <div id="loading-overlay">
   <div class="loading-spinner"></div>
  </div>

  <!--Website Header-->
  <div id="header">
   <div class="steam-login">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-steam">
     <div class="sign-in-text">Steam Sign-In</div>
    </i></a>
   </div>
  </div>

  <!--Website Sidebar-->
  <div id="sidebar-menu">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class=""></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-area-chart"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-life-ring"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Set `.steam-login a : display:block; ` to `.steam-login a : display:inline-block; `

Comment: I tried but it didn't do anything.

Comment: "center next to" is not quite precise. Do you want to center it or d you want to put it aside the text ? What is the specific text class you're referring to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always good to use flexbox when you need to align to items side by side and vertically middle. Also it is safe if you do not write text inside the `<i>` tag you are using `font-awesome` on. wrap the text in a `span` and put it outside the `<i>` tag, that way you won't mix up the css for text and the icon.

Here, I have changed the html and css for elements that are inside the `<div cass="steam-login">` only. Rest of the code is same.

```css
/* Default Stuff */
    * {
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
     text-decoration:none;
     list-style:none;
     font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
    }

    /* Loading Animation */
    .loading-spinner {
     width:100px;
     height:100px;
     border:2px solid rgb(255,255,255);
     border-top:3px solid rgb(250,32,32);
     border-radius:100%;
     position:absolute;
     top:0px;
     bottom:0px;
     left:0px;
     right:0px;
     margin:auto;
     animation:loading-spin 1s infinite linear;
    }

    @keyframes loading-spin {
     from {
      transform:rotate(0deg);
     } to {
      transform:rotate(360deg);
     }
    }

    #loading-overlay {
     height:100%;
     width:100%;
     background:rgb(17,17,17);
     position:fixed;
     z-index:9999999999;
     left:0px;
     top:0px;
    }

    /* Website Header */
    #header {
     background:rgb(28,28,28);
     width:100%;
     height:60px;
     position:absolute;
     box-shadow:0px 0px 8px 2px black;
     border-top:3px solid rgb(235,50,50);
     z-index:99999999;
     left:0px;
     top:0px;
    }

    .steam-login {
     background:rgb(50,50,50);
     border-left:3px solid rgb(235,50,50);;
     width:160px;
     height:40px;
     position:absolute;
     z-index:999999999;
     top:13px;
     left:1160px;
    }

    .steam-login a {
     display:block;
     color:rgb(255,255,255);
     height:100%;
     width:100%;
     margin-left:5px;
     font-size:30px;
    }
    .sign-in-text{
     display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .sign-in-text>span{
     color:white;
     font-size:8px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
     margin-left:10px;
    }

    /* Sidebar Menu */
    #sidebar-menu {
     background:rgb(41,41,41);
     width:60px;
     height:100%;
     position:absolute;
     text-align:center;
     line-height:60px;
     box-shadow:4px 4px 8px black;
     left:0px;
     top:0px;
    }

    ul {
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
     margin-top:3px;
    }

    ul li {
     list-style:none;
     height:60px;
     border-bottom:2px solid rgb(17,17,17);
    }

    ul li a {
     color:rgb(255,255,255);
     font-size:30px;
     display:block;
     height:100%
     width:100%;
    }

    ul li a:hover {
     background:rgb(255,255,255);
     color:rgb(41,41,41);
    }

    ul li a:active {
     font-size:25px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Loading Animation
  <div id="loading-overlay">
   <div class="loading-spinner"></div>
  </div>-->

  <!--Website Header-->
  <div id="header">
   <div class="steam-login">
    <a href="#">
                  <div class="sign-in-text"><i class="fa fa-steam "></i><span>Steam Sign-In</span></div>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>

  <!--Website Sidebar-->
  <div id="sidebar-menu">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class=""></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-area-chart"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-life-ring"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: @Abyssal   .. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Ok just one more thing how would I center these horizontally because I don't remember how to do it on flexbox.

Comment: In flexbox, `align-items:center;` centers vertically and `justify-content:center;` centers horizontally. Thanks.